# Protect any cell after inserting value

Tags: excel, vba

i want to make a excel sheet where anyone can insert data. but once user insert data after that user can't change. only one person say admin can change data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved by myself. Solution

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c1 As Range
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
For Each c1 In Target
If c1.Value <> "" Then
c1.Locked = True
End If
Next c1
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123"
End Sub
```

Comment: This solution as provided does not work. You have to add that one in a first step has to set the format of all cells to _unlocked_.